# Model data in schema create with custom connection

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I've an `AppSchema` where I insert some rows into MySQL. So far so good:

```
$foo = ClassRegistry::init('Foo');
$foo->create();
$foo->saveMany(/*...*/);
```

I've learnt that `--connection` switch is [intentionally](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html#cakeschema-callbacks) overridden by each `Model::$useDbConfig`:

> If you use models in your callbacks make sure to initialize them with
>   the correct datasource, lest they fallback to their default
>   datasources:
>
> ```
> public function before($event = array()) {
>     $articles = ClassRegistry::init('Articles', array(
>         'ds' => $this->connection
>     ));
>     // Do things with articles.
> }
> ```

Yet I'm unable to insert my rows in anything else than `default`:

```
Console/cake schema create --connection test --file schema_foo.php
```

```
class AppSchema extends CakeSchema {
    public function __construct($options = array()) {
        parent::__construct($options);
        // `$this->connection` contains value from `--connection`
        $foo = ClassRegistry::init('Foo', array('ds' => $this->connection));
        // `--connection` is ignored, `default` gets initialised
        $foo->create();
        $foo->saveMany(/*...*/);
    }
}
```

What did I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cookbook example is wrong, there is no such syntax, the second argument of `ClassRegistry::init()` is a boolean.

The first argument accepts an array to pass further options:

```
ClassRegistry::init(array(
    'class' => 'Foo'
    'ds' => $this->connection
));
```

See also the slightly broken API docs **[API > ClassRegistry::init()](https://api.cakephp.org/2.10/class-ClassRegistry.html#_init)** :)